# Bootstrap - Linear gradient buttons not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the button gradient in Bootstrap. But it doesn't work.

My CSS:

```
.btn-grad {background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #4776E6 0%, #8E54E9 51%, #4776E6 100%)}
.btn-grad:hover { background-position: right center; }
```

And my code:

```
<a class="btn btn-grad text-white">
 <p>ACCESS ON THE WEB</p>
</a>
```

Expected result:

```
When I brought the mouse over it, it should have worked animatedly. It looks just like an image.
```

Here is the result:
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2zYl.png)

Comment: I edited now. When I brought the mouse over it, it should have worked animatedly. But now, it looks like an image.

Comment: Note that 'right center' is equivalent to 100% 50% so your understand why the duplicate. (you will also find it in the duplicate by the way)